# return statements should not be cuddled if block has more than two lines (wsl)

Tags: go

My golint returns this error message but i don't really understand what it means.

As in title:

`return statements should not be cuddled if block has more than two lines (wsl)`

my code is this:

```golang
func validateCountry(product models.Product, countries []models.Country) bool {
    if !product.CountryCode.Valid {
        return true
    }

    for _, country := range countries {
        if country.Code == product.CountryCode.String {
            return !country.Enabled && country.Deprecated
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

What the linter does not like seems to be the last `return false`.

I'm very confused, i didn't setup the linter in this codebase, and i don't really know how to either skip this rules or how to fix it.

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from [this linter](https://github.com/bombsimon/wsl).

Comment: What is the error? You never pasted the error.

Comment: is in the title, but i should add it here as well.

Comment: Are you sure you reproduced the whitespace accurately here? The readme suggests that you're [missing an empty line before the return statement](https://github.com/bombsimon/wsl/blob/master/README.md#return).

Comment: Your code looks fine, "linting" it with my own eyes showed very readable code. This is the metric that counts in the end. As others said, maybe the your code is not really the same as you posted here or maybe the linter is broken. At the end it does not matter much. Tools like this are not absolute in their decisions. Linters produce merely hints, not hard rules to follow, although you should of course inspect all issues that they raise, most will be sensible. Still, ignore this one and continue working :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This error means that, in your case, you need to put a blank line before any next return statement:

```
[empty line] <-- need this
return true
...
[empty line] <-- need this
return !country.Enabled && country.Deprecated
```

`should not be cuddled` means there must be no code lines near the return statement.

Comment: My 5 cent here for golangci - all the linters are listed in https://golangci-lint.run/usage/linters/ and you can easily find the by their code at the end of the message, e.g. "return statements should not be cuddled if block has more than two lines (wsl)" is WSL

Comment: Maybe I am an idiot. but why the heck doesn't it just say (you need an empty new line above the return)